# Odd merge on git hub

Tags: github, git-merge

Our git hub is showing a wierd merge.  I had made a couple small changes to our master branch on git hub and then merged the branch into our develop branch.  However at the same time as the merge from master to develop Master is showing a merge from develop into master, however the associated pull request is for the merge from master into develop.

Is this just a bug in the reporting?

Here are screen shots of the merges.

[image]

[image]